# unresolved external symbol in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am writing code for a heap which supports decPrio operation. But I'm getting unresolved external symbol error when I use the code.

```
template< typename PRIO, typename VALUE>
class Node;

template< typename PRIO, typename VALUE, typename CMP = std::less<PRIO> >
class FibonacciHeap{

    //Interface:

    //a typedef for a type "item", which acts as a pointer to an element in the queue
    //(item is used below in various methods).

    public:
        typedef Node<PRIO,VALUE>* item;
        typedef int size_t;
        CMP cmp;

    private:
        item m_roots;
        int item_count;

    public:
                void decPrio(item it, const PRIO &prio);
                item insert(const PRIO &prio, const VALUE &value);

        private:

        void link(item x,item y);
        void cut(item x,item y);
        void cascadeCut(item y);
};

template< typename PRIO, typename VALUE>
class Node{

    friend class FibonacciHeap<PRIO,VALUE>;
    int degree;
    bool marked;
    Node<PRIO,VALUE>* parent;
    Node<PRIO,VALUE>* child;
    Node<PRIO,VALUE>* left;
    Node<PRIO,VALUE>* right;

    public:
        PRIO prio;
        VALUE value;
        Node(PRIO p,VALUE v) : 
        degree(0),marked(0), parent(NULL),child(NULL),left(NULL),right(NULL),prio(p),value(v) {}

};

template<typename PRIO,typename VALUE,typename CMP>
void decPrio(typename FibonacciHeap<PRIO,VALUE,CMP>::item it, const PRIO &prio)
{
    if(m_roots==NULL)
        return;

    if(it==NULL)
        return;

    if(!cmp(prio,it->prio))
        return;

    it->prio=prio;
    item y =it->parent;

    if(y!=NULL && cmp(it->prio,y->prio))
    {
        cut(it,y);
        cascadeCut(y);
    }

    if(cmp(it->prio,m_roots->prio))
        m_roots=it;

}
```

Here is my main code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "myfib.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){

    FibonacciHeap<int,int> f;
    FibonacciHeap<int,int>::item temp;

        temp=f.insert(30,1);
    f.decPrio(temp,2);

    return 0;

}
```

I'm getting the error message:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall `FibonacciHeap<int,int,struct std::less<int> >::decPrio(class Node<int,int> *,int const &)`" (?decPrio@?$FibonacciHeap@HHU?$less@H@std@@@@QAEXPAV?$Node@HH@@ABH@Z) referenced in function _main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template<typename PRIO,typename VALUE,typename CMP>
void decPrio(typename FibonacciHeap<PRIO,VALUE,CMP>::item it, const PRIO &prio)
{
```

should be

```
template<typename PRIO,typename VALUE,typename CMP>
void FibonacciHeap<PRIO,VALUE,CMP>::decPrio(Node<PRIO,VALUE>* it, const PRIO &prio)
{
```